Why is the bundle size smaller when using a pre-bundled library (A1) compared to a non-bundled version (A2)?
There's a library called A. A1 is built using a bundler(Vite), while A2 is built without using a bundler. only tsc.
In the case of A1, the size is enormous because libraries like React are bundled together. On the other hand, A2 is not built with a bundler, so the size is not as large.
In a project, I installed the library A via npm. Once I installed A1, and once I installed A2. A1 and A2 are the same library, only differing by whether a bundler was used. When I built the project for deployment using the Vite bundler, the results were different between using A1 and A2.
I expected that A1, being a single bundle already, would be harder to tree-shake, making the project's bundle size larger compared to using A2. However, the reality was the opposite. Why is that?
Type A1 -> folder size after build (bundled) -> 60.3KB
Type B1 -> folder size after build (tsc only) -> 2.03KB
---
but,
Same Project with Lib A1 -> build size with Vite bundler -> 166.06KB
Same project with Lib A2 -> build size with Vite bundler -> 166.48KB // I thought it should be smaller than above!

Without seeing details, I guess that the end project already uses React, and React is only put into the bundle once. The bundler (probably) can evaluate imports, creates a list of needed modules, and doesn't include the same module twice.

Oh, even you bundled into one .js file, end project knows what to import? I thought when bundling has finished, there's no more chance to treeshake anymore.

Actually I'm not absolutely sure. You are right, the bundler would need to know which modules they were, so there must be some kind of meta information still inside the bundled code. I can't imagine the bundler just knows how the code looks like ... Now I'm curious, I will check myself (when I have time).

I tested it to make it sure. After bundled, it is hard for bundler to know what to treeshake. Because behind this treeshake mechanism, bundler draws a dependency graph from import & exports statements. Once bundled, all the js files packed up as one single js file, so it is hard to (I cannot say impossible) treeshake.
We cannot say bundler is always the best answer for optimizing bundle size. We should consider what kind of dependencies have in common for each projects.
